# Python don't do anything until keystroke

Tags: python, keystroke

So basically I need a Python program or a module that only executes the main program once a *specific* key is pressed, for example the F10 key. All the other modules I found (for example getch) executes once *any* key it pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `msvcrt`, I'll assume that (Windows).  You'd do it different in Linux.

`F10` is a 2-byte return, `00 68`, so...  you look for the first byte `00`, then the second byte `68`.  There is also a 2-byte return that has a `224` for the first byte, so you'll want to check for that, too.

I included a block on `kbhit()` because if you let it block on `getch()` instead, it will pick up a `Ctrl-C` and you won't be able to break out. Blocking on this gives you that opportunity.

You can make this a little more generic if you'd like, this is hardcoded for `F10`.

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        first = ord(msvcrt.getch())     
        if first in (0, 224):
            second = ord(msvcrt.getch())
            if first == 0 and second == 68:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using `getch`, you might as well loop over it and wait for your key:

```
while getch() != 'MAGIC KEY':
    pass
```

This will forever run `getch`, until the user presses the key you want. Then the flow continues as normal.